# Multiple cell prototypes in Dynamic TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I want to create a table like this in which on there will be two cells in one section. In first cell the profile image comes and description in the second cell. what I have tried so far is I have set Prototypes to 2 and give each prototype a unique identifier and also created two classes for two prototypes. But The problem is it is showing two rows but both rows have same data.

```
var profileImage = ["angelina","kevin"]
    var userName = ["Angelina Jolie","Vasiliy Pupkin"]
    var requestTitle = ["I have a Wordpress website and I am looking for someone to create a landing page with links and a cart to link up.","second description"]
    var date = ["Feb 03, 16","Feb 03, 16"]

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return profileImage.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return profileImage.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



            if(indexPath.row==0){
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstProductRequestTableViewCell

                cell.userNameLabel.text = userName[indexPath.row]
                cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: profileImage[indexPath.row])
                return cell

            }else{




                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondProductRequestTableViewCell

               cell.requestTitleTxtView.text = requestTitle[indexPath.row]
                return cell

                      }
               }
```

Comment: Can you add your numberOfRowsInSection method?

Comment: okay now problem is it repeats the same row two times. I'll update my question

Comment: You should return 2 in numberOfRowsInSection if you want 2 rows for each section. Try to add a breakpoint in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function to check if the else is executed

Comment: well I have tried this still getting the same duplicate rows which are two rows

Comment: Ok, the problem is clear, but the else is executed or not? Do you implement the heightForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: yes else is executing. no I didn't implement the height function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for your question.

You need to use **UITableViewSecionHeaderView** in this case because i think in your scenario you have multiple descriptions against a profile so put the **SecionHeader** which contain the information of profile and cells contain the description.

But if you want to Repeat the whole cell then you only need to make a CustomCell which contain profile information and description with a line separator. You can make a line separator with an Image or using UIView of height 1.0 and colour lightgray.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the number of sections returned is correct, but you should return `2` for the number of rows in each section and when configuring the cells you should be using `indexPath.section` where you're currently using the row to choose the data to add to the cell (but keep using the row to choose which type of cell to return).

So, the section is used to choose which person you're showing details about and the row is used to choose which piece of information to show:

```
var profileImage = ["angelina","kevin"]
var userName = ["Angelina Jolie","Vasiliy Pupkin"]
var requestTitle = ["I have a Wordpress website and I am looking for someone to create a landing page with links and a cart to link up.","second description"]
var date = ["Feb 03, 16","Feb 03, 16"]

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return profileImage.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstProductRequestTableViewCell

        cell.userNameLabel.text = userName[indexPath.row]
        cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: profileImage[indexPath.section])

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondProductRequestTableViewCell
        cell.requestTitleTxtView.text = requestTitle[indexPath.section]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. okay I have followed your answer and I done this 
if (indexPath.section == 0){fill first cell} else { fill the next cell}
and now the problem is cells are not coming correctly

Comment: Updated the answer to make it clear where yo use section and where to use row

Comment: Okay yes I checked your edited answer. now I am confused. could you please explain me through code by using my code